# When I purchase a Steam key on Humble Bundle, does Valve receive any money?

Tags: humble-bundle

I want to buy a game available only through Steam, but I don't agree with Valve's business practices and don't want to support them. If I buy a Steam key from Humble Bundle, how much money, if any does Valve receive? Is it less than if I had purchased directly from the Steam store?

Humble Bundle support did not seem to understand the question and gave an ambiguous reply.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as it does not apply to gaming itself. See [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12134/162442).

Answer (score 4):

## No.

[Steam allows developers to generate keys](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/keys) (for free of course) to sell their games elsewhere. Valve only collect a cut of the profits **if the item was purchased directly through the Steam Store**.

As for the case of Humble Bundle however, developers do get their money, however, it is split evenly based on the percentages you have specified in the purchase dialog.

[image]

For the case of this screenshot, the <s>developer</s> publisher gets a majority of the proceeds, though because this is Humble Bundle, you can change the distribution of where your money goes (ie. all the charity)